# Why I can't import any library?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import, python-module

My problem is quite simple, but I can't get over it. I have installed the IDLE 3.6 of Python, as well as anaconda. Now, everytime I write

> import numpy

I get

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'

Although anaconda confirms me it is a regularly installed package. The IDLE program is in the same root of Python 3.6 Module docs so I assume there shouldn't be any problem with the path of the module, but it seems like I may be wrong. While installing, I let python do its thing so I went for all the recommended steps. Nontheless I do not understand what the problem is.

Comment: Use VSCode or Sublime or something similar instead of IDLE. Then, change the python interpreter where your Conda python.exe is.

Answer (score 0):

wont let me comment, but do you have pip installed ? that's the only reason i can think of.

Comment: I appreciate, but I was able to resolve in some way so thanks!

Comment: There were some problems regarding the enviroment variable. I installed again python, checked wether the command "python" on the cmd worked and the job was done.

Answer (score -1):

you need to **install the module**!

`pip install numpy`
or
`pip3 install numpy`

see more info here: https://numpy.org/install/

Comment: It is already installed. Nontheless I did try to run 'pip install numpy' several times, which always gave me errors.

Comment: the error says the module is not installed. you might be running different different versions of python to install the module and run the program. Instead of vote down try to read and understand the problem

Comment: It wasn't me, my low points do not allow me to vote up nor down.